# Statistics Issue Related to Percentages and Corresponding Z-Scores

Tags: statistics, percentages, percentile

I had a disagreement with my professor about this specific problem recently and so I though it would be good to get some other input on the matter.  Here's the question:

> 22% of a population of fish are more than 45 cm in length and 14 % are more than 55 cm in length.  What is the mean length and standard deviation of the lengths of the fish?

We were given a z-score lookup table to solve this problem with the following values: `-0.77 -> 0.2206` and `0.78 -> 0.2177`

I used the z-score value of -0.77, converted to 0.77, because the percentage was closer to the 22% from the question. However my professor believed the correct value should be 0.78.  I believe his reasoning was that you needed to have a z-score value that fit *within* the 22% of data because the question said *more than 22%*.

Any discussion/help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Assuming no rounding and no missing values, "22% of a population of fish are more than 45 cm in length" is equivalent to "78% of a population of fish are 45 cm in length or less"

Comment: @Henry So would you say that a z-score of 0.77 or 0.78 would be more accurate?